# React typescript: RouterProps: An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am using Typescript in a React project, and I have this code that I got with the help of Chatgpt:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";

interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      element={token ? children : <Navigate to="/login" replace />}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

It is showing this error:

> An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object
> types with statically known members.

The error is coming from "extends RouteProps" in this line:

```js
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Comment: Yet another reason why ChatGPT isn't the invaluable tool people make it out to be.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because RouteProps isn't an interface, it's a union of multiple interfaces. From the react-router-dom 6.3.0 type definitions:

```
export declare type RouteProps = PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps
```

You can't extend an interface from a union, but you can do essentially the same thing with a type intersection:

```
type PrivateRouteProps = RouteProps & {
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
```

There are some very slight differences between extending an interface and doing an intersection, but they rarely matter. If you'd like to know more see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is that you can't extend a type declaration, you can only extend interfaces. Nicholas's answer addresses this sufficiently and there is not more I could add.

[Source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/19e6398f20779dd34d8b4eca0f3605bf5831a7f0/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L336-L378)

> ```
> export interface PathRouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: NonIndexRouteObject["caseSensitive"];
>   path?: NonIndexRouteObject["path"];
>   id?: NonIndexRouteObject["id"];
>   lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<NonIndexRouteObject>;
>   loader?: NonIndexRouteObject["loader"];
>   action?: NonIndexRouteObject["action"];
>   hasErrorBoundary?: NonIndexRouteObject["hasErrorBoundary"];
>   shouldRevalidate?: NonIndexRouteObject["shouldRevalidate"];
>   handle?: NonIndexRouteObject["handle"];
>   index?: false;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   hydrateFallbackElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   Component?: React.ComponentType | null;
>   HydrateFallback?: React.ComponentType | null;
>   ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
> }
>
> export interface LayoutRouteProps extends PathRouteProps {}
>
> export interface IndexRouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: IndexRouteObject["caseSensitive"];
>   path?: IndexRouteObject["path"];
>   id?: IndexRouteObject["id"];
>   lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<IndexRouteObject>;
>   loader?: IndexRouteObject["loader"];
>   action?: IndexRouteObject["action"];
>   hasErrorBoundary?: IndexRouteObject["hasErrorBoundary"];
>   shouldRevalidate?: IndexRouteObject["shouldRevalidate"];
>   handle?: IndexRouteObject["handle"];
>   index: true;
>   children?: undefined;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   hydrateFallbackElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   Component?: React.ComponentType | null;
>   HydrateFallback?: React.ComponentType | null;
>   ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
> }
>
> export type RouteProps = PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps;
> ```

You can "extend" the union. Something along the following:

```js
type PrivateRouteProps = RouteProps & {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

## But

But after you fix the Typescript issue you are going to run into React-Router-DOM issues trying to use this `PrivateRoute` component.

- `Route` component `children` can only be another `Route` component.
- The `Route` component can't be rendered directly, it can only be rendered as a child of the `Routes` component, or the `Route` component in the case of nested routes.

Instead of rendering a `children` prop, an `Outlet` component should be rendered for the nested routes to render out their content. This also really simplifies the implementation.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  return token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Usage:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoutes />} >
      {/* Protected routes */}
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
    </Route>

    {/* Unprotected routes */}
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```